# Go from finitely generated module to free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Given a finitely generated $R$-module $M$, suppose there is a set of generators $m_1, \cdots m_n$. If we could show that $\{m_i\}$ are linearly independent, does this imply $M$ is free?

I think it should since if $\{m_i\}$ are linearly independent, then the map 
$$\phi: M \rightarrow R^n \quad \text{ where } \quad m=\sum_i r_im_i \mapsto (r_1, \cdots, r_n)$$ 
is both injective and surjective.

Is this correct?

Comment: But can't you just reduce the collection of generators into a linearly-independent set anyway?

Comment: @gary no in general. If it is torsion-free, then yes. I don't know much besides that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an equivalent definition of a free module is that it has a basis, i.e it has a set of generators that are linearly independent.